# How implement class to have tag form:date by extends InputTag with Spring

Tags: forms, jsp, spring-mvc

I want to use the tag "form:date" on a spring form

```
<form:form id="saveAction" commandName="commandName" action="/save" method="post">
  <form:errors path="name" cssClass="error"/>
  <form:date path="name" cssStyle="input date" cssErrorClass="inputError"/>
</form>
```

How can I create and implement a class who extends org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag to can use form:date to generate a input type="date".

I use Spring web mvc 2.5.5.

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose for this when lots of css classes that seamlessly converts an input as a date for you?